# Python: Long Form of Array For Loop

Tags: python

In Python, the short form for building an array via a `bracketized for` loop is:

```
def get_row(runner):
    row = some_complicated_function()
    return row

my_array = [get_row(runner) for runner in range(10000)]
```

How would this look like if I want to avoid the condensed form of `for` loop?

Comment: _"How would this look like if I want to avoid the condensed form of for loop?"_ - `my_array = []; for runner in range(10000): my_array.append(get_row(runner))`.

Comment: cool. thanks. And is this comparable with regards to performance/speed?

Comment: @user8042669 list-comprehensions tend to be faster since they [remove some overhead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30245397/why-is-a-list-comprehension-so-much-faster-than-appending-to-a-list) of accessing list.append.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure @user8042669. I suspect the list comp would be faster. Why not try it out yourself :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code snippet (the one you provided is the list-comprehension)

```
my_array = [get_row(runner) for runner in range(10000)]
```

Here is an equivalent `unrolled` version

```
my_array = []
for runner in range(10000):
    row_runner = get_row(runner)
    my_array.append(row_runner)
    # alternatively
    # my_array.append(get_row(runner))
```