# Can I use apply() or anyting else on a 1-dim dataframe to construct a list of dataframes?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Is there any way to construct a list of dataframes from a 1-dim dataframe or list? I thought apply would do the trick but it seems not to be the case. The job can be done easily by using a for loop but I wish to avoid that. More details down below.

This is the code I tried but it wouldn't work

```py
pd.DataFrame([1,2,3,4,5]).apply(lambda x: pd.DataFrame([x]))
```

This is the code that would do the trick but for loop is what I wish to avoid at all cost, do run it so that you know what I actually try to achieve

```py
list = [1,2,3,4,5]
j = []
for i in list:
    i = pd.DataFrame([i])
    j = j + [i]
```

In the project I work on, the thing I wish to do would be much more complex than just turning a element into a 1x1 dataframe but rather transforming it into a huge dataframe and eventually each of the dataframes generated would be put into a list, the only bottleneck is exactly this issue I described, 
 thanks in advance.

Comment: What is your expected output exactly?

Comment: a list with dataframes as elements, in the example I have, I need [pd.DataFrame([1]), pd.DataFrame([2]), pd.DataFrame([3]), pd.DataFrame([4]), pd.DataFrame([5])]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify and speed up your loop by using list comprehension which takes away the overhead of a `for loop`, [here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30245397/why-is-a-list-comprehension-so-much-faster-than-appending-to-a-list) a good read on it

***Note**: I renamed your list to `lst` since "list" is a reserved word in Python, don't use it as an variable*

```
dfs = [pd.DataFrame([x]) for x in lst]
```

Now we can access each dataframe:

```
print(dfs[0])

   0
0  1

print(dfs[1])

   0
0  2
```