# Can I create a numpy array of dictionary values from an array of dictionary keys?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, dictionary

Say I have a dictionary:

```
d = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'd': 4, 'e': 5}
```

Given a numpy array** of keys, e.g. `['a' 'c' 'e']`, is there an easy way to create a numpy array of the corresponding values, e.g. `[1 3 5]`?

** for reasons of the context I'm using this in, I'd prefer to input/output numpy arrays. Something similar can obviously be done with lists:

```
keys = ['a', 'c', 'e']
values = []

for k in keys:
    values.append(d[k])

print(values)
[1, 3, 5]
```

But I am wondering if there is a built-in way to do something like this in numpy.

Comment: No, the compiled `numpy` code does not have anything special for dictionaries.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this with a [structured array](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.rec.html?highlight=structured%20array#module-numpy.doc.structured_arrays) and [`np.in1d`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.in1d.html).

```
import numpy as np

d = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'd': 4, 'e': 5}

# Create structured array (modify formats, names as necessary):
names = ['key', 'data']  
formats = ['U10', 'i4']                                                                        
dtype = dict(names = names, formats = formats)

arr = np.array(list(d.items()), dtype=dtype)

# >>> arr
# array([('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('c', 3), ('d', 4), ('e', 5)],
#       dtype=[('key', '<U10'), ('data', '<i4')])

# use np.in1d to get your keys:

keys = ['a', 'c', 'e']

values = arr[np.in1d(arr['key'], keys)]['data']                                                

# >>> values
# array([1, 3, 5], dtype=int32)
```

Comment: This is incredibly convoluted and essentially pointless (turning an O(1) looking into an O(n)). I love it.

Answer (score 1):

If you just require to have numpy arrays as input and output but don't insist on using a numpy *function* to handle them, you can use `numpy.array()` on the result of a list comprehension:

```
import numpy as np

d = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'd': 4, 'e': 5}
keys = np.array(['a', 'c', 'e'])
values = np.array([d[k] for k in keys])

print(values)
```

Comment: A list comprehension is a streamlined for loop, but otherwise not much a change from the OP's approach.

Comment: I would still recommend to use list comprehension over append, because it is [much faster](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30245397/1843468).