# How does list-comprehension "create list" and "append elements" different than simple loop?

Tags: python, list, loops, list-comprehension

While I was reading and searching about what exactly causes performance difference between loops and list comprehension (based on below simple test cases, list comprehension faster), I encountered following posts here in SO:

**Simple test cases:**

```
def f1():
    t = []
    for i in range(10000):
        t.append(i)

def f2():
    t = [i for i in range(10000)]
```

[Why is a list comprehension so much faster than appending to a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30245397/why-is-a-list-comprehension-so-much-faster-than-appending-to-a-list)

[Are list-comprehensions and functional functions faster than “for loops”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22108488/are-list-comprehensions-and-functional-functions-faster-than-for-loops)

What I understand from above posts that main differences as follows;

1. For loop builds a list but, list comprehension does not
2. For loop loads append method on each iteration but, list comprehension does not

Then I used disassembler to see the details and I saw the below steps for following block of code:

**Code:**

```
def f2():
    t = [i for i in range(10000)]
    
dis.dis(f2)
```

**Disassembler result:**

```
0 BUILD_LIST              
2 LOAD_FAST                
4 FOR_ITER                 
6 STORE_FAST               
8 LOAD_FAST                
10 LIST_APPEND        
12 JUMP_ABSOLUTE            
14 RETURN_VALUE
```

Based on Python [doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dis.html); `0 BUILD_LIST` creates list and `10 LIST_APPEND` uses append method by contrast with above related posts:

```
LIST_APPEND(i)
    Calls list.append(TOS[-i], TOS). Used to implement list comprehensions.

BUILD_LIST(count)
    Works as BUILD_TUPLE, but creates a list.
```

I could not figure out what I am missing here. Is the way list comprehension *builds* and *appends* different than for loop, because anyway `LIST_APPEND` contains `append` method and `BUILD_LIST` creates a list? or maybe the reason for the performance difference is something else? Can someone please clarify this for me?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I think if you *also* use `dis.dis` on the for-loop version, the differences will become apparent to you.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel you are right, actually I did, there were additional steps, such as GET_ITER and CALL_METHOD. But in this case, difference between them is not mainly loading `append` method in each iteration or creating list as it is mentioned in given posts in my questions, is that right?

Comment: `LIST_APPEND` can *directly* use the C implementation of the method; when the code contains an `.append` call, that method has to be looked up through the normal mechanisms. My `dis` results look completely different from yours, though. Are you on 2.x?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I am on 3.8.2. So `LIST_APPEND` actually not calling `append` method but using its C implementation. And regular `append` method in my code loads the method on each iteration, and this is the difference, did I understand correctly?

Comment: @Sercan it *is* calling `.append`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga thank you, I did not notice the difference, that makes sense now

Answer (score 2):

I've tried a different approach:

```py
from collections import Counter


def f1():
    t = []
    for i in range(10000):
        t.append(i)

def f2():
    t = [i for i in range(10000)]

    
f1i = Counter(i.opname for i in dis.get_instructions(f1))
f2i = Counter(i.opname for i in dis.get_instructions(f2))

print(f"Only in regular append: {f1i - f2i}")
print(f"Only in list comprehension: {f2i - f1i}")
```

The results are (Python 3.7.6):

```
Only in regular append: Counter({'LOAD_FAST': 2, 'BUILD_LIST': 1, 'STORE_FAST': 1, 'SETUP_LOOP': 1, 'FOR_ITER': 1, 'LOAD_METHOD': 1, 'CALL_METHOD': 1, 'POP_TOP': 1, 'JUMP_ABSOLUTE': 1, 'POP_BLOCK': 1})
Only in list comprehension: Counter({'LOAD_CONST': 2, 'MAKE_FUNCTION': 1, 'CALL_FUNCTION': 1})
```

You can see that the "regular" append uses `LOAD_METHOD` (for `list.append`), `LOAD_FAST`, `CALL_METHOD` and `POP_TOP` each iteration:

```
dis.dis(f1)
```

```
  5           0 BUILD_LIST               0
              2 STORE_FAST               0 (t)

  6           4 SETUP_LOOP              26 (to 32)
              6 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (range)
              8 LOAD_CONST               1 (10000)
             10 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             12 GET_ITER
        >>   14 FOR_ITER                14 (to 30)
             16 STORE_FAST               1 (i)

  7          18 LOAD_FAST                0 (t)
             20 LOAD_METHOD              1 (append)
             22 LOAD_FAST                1 (i)
             24 CALL_METHOD              1
             26 POP_TOP
             28 JUMP_ABSOLUTE           14
        >>   30 POP_BLOCK
        >>   32 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             34 RETURN_VALUE
```

It is also recommended to keep in mind that the opcodes change from one version to another.

Comment: Thank you, both @KarlKnechtel comments and your explanation are clear and useful. I was confused because I also saw `append` method in `LIST_APPEND` description

Comment: But you aren't actually looking at the byt code for the comprehension

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Is the result of `dis.dis` not byte code? I have looked for an option `view byte code` like in intellij idea for java, but could not find it. After googling, I found `dis.dis` to see byte code. Any link or direction you can give me to see byte code?

Comment: The point is that the work done inside the comprehension is hidden behind (I think) `CALL_FUNCTION`. It becomes a separate chunk of bytecode that `dis` doesn't reach into (at least when used naively).