# Find index span of a sub list from a list

Tags: python, list

Given a list of string L, and a sublist M from L. I want to find an efficient way to find the index span (index_a, index_b) from L where L[index_a: index_b] = M.

For example,

```
L = ['Clement', 'Joseph', 'Man', '##ey', 'was', 'an', 'American', 'businessman', 'from', 'Boston', 'who', 'was', 'president', 'of', 'a', 'contracting', 'company', 'and', 'a', 'minority', 'owner', 'and', 'treasurer', 'of', 'the', 'Boston', 'Braves', 'baseball', 'team', '.']
M = ['Clement', 'Joseph', 'Man', '##ey']

Expected_result = (0,4) # since L[0:4] = M

L = ['Clement', 'Joseph', 'Man', '##ey', 'was', 'an', 'American', 'businessman', 'from', 'Boston', 'who', 'was', 'president', 'of', 'a', 'contracting', 'company', 'and', 'a', 'minority', 'owner', 'and', 'treasurer', 'of', 'the', 'Boston', 'Braves', 'baseball', 'team', '.']
M = ['Boston']

Expected_result = (9,9) # both (9,9) and (25,25) are correct since L[9]=L[25]=M
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a comprehension,and check the length when return the value:

```
def getIndex(lst1, lst2):
    index1 = next((i for i in range(len(lst1) - len(lst2)) if lst1[i:i + len(lst2)] == lst2), None)
    if index1 is not None: # when sub list doesn't exist in another list
        return (index1, index1) if len(lst2) == 1 else (index1, index1+len(lst2))
    else:
        return None
```

```
L1 = ['Clement', 'Joseph', 'Man', '##ey', 'was', 'an', 'American', 'businessman', 'from', 'Boston', 'who', 'was',
     'president', 'of', 'a', 'contracting', 'company', 'and', 'a', 'minority', 'owner', 'and', 'treasurer', 'of', 'the',
     'Boston', 'Braves', 'baseball', 'team', '.']
M1 = ['Clement', 'Joseph', 'Man', '##ey']

L2 = ['Clement', 'Joseph', 'Man', '##ey', 'was', 'an', 'American', 'businessman', 'from', 'Boston', 'who', 'was', 'president', 'of', 'a', 'contracting', 'company', 'and', 'a', 'minority', 'owner', 'and', 'treasurer', 'of', 'the', 'Boston', 'Braves', 'baseball', 'team', '.']
M2 = ['Boston']

print(getIndex(L1, M1))
print(getIndex(L2, M2))
```

Result:

```
(0, 4)
(9, 9)
```

---

Or one line:

```
def getIndex(lst1, lst2):
    return next(((i, i + (len(lst2) if len(lst2) > 1 else 0)) for i in range(len(lst1) - len(lst2)) if lst1[i:i + len(lst2)] == lst2), None)
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I am not very familiar with the `next` function and I wonder whether using it would be more efficient than using a simple loop over the list?

Comment: @Garvey Check this:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30245397/why-is-a-list-comprehension-so-much-faster-than-appending-to-a-list.

Answer (score 1):

```
def getIndices(L,M):
    results = []
    for i in range(len(L) - len(M)):
        if L[i:i+len(M)] == M:
            results.append((i, i+len(M)))
    return results
```

Traversing the list `L` in blocks of `len(M)`and checking if it's equal to the list `M`