# How to speed up this Pandas for loop

Tags: python, pandas, performance, for-loop

I have the following data in Python:

```
list1=[[ENS_ID1,ENS_ID2,ENS_ID3], [ENS_ID10,ENS_ID24,ENS_ID30] , ....]
```

mapping (a dataframe where in the first column I have an Ensemble gene ID and in the second column the corresponding MGI gene ID)

| ENS_ID | MGI_ID |
| --- | --- |
| ENS_ID1 | MGI_ID1 |
| ENS_ID2 | MGI_ID2 |

I'm trying to obtain another list of lists where instead of the ENS_ID I have the MGI_ID.
To map the IDs I'm using a for cycle nested inside another one, but obviously, it's really slow as an approach.
How can I speed it up?
Here's the code:

```
for l in ens_lists:
  mgi = []
  for i in l:
      mgi.append(mapping['MGI_ID'][mapping[mapping['ENSEMBL_ID']==i].index].values[0])
  mgi_lists.append(mgi)
```

Comment: no idea if its quicker but can you sort them and zip?

Comment: Loops in python are very slow. You might look up `multithreading` to speedup performance.

Comment: I was thinking if there's a different way to do it without loops

Comment: Could you please elaborate a little more about the structure of `mapping` ? I though `ENS_ID` and `MGI_ID` were simple constant, but the line `mapping['MGI_ID'][mapping[mapping['ENSEMBL_ID']==i].index].values[0]` make me think the structure is more complex than a simple dict...

Comment: mapping it's a dataframe where in the first column I have an Ensemble gene ID and in the second column the corresponding MGI gene ID

Comment: @surftijmen Multithreading won't help with pure Python code due to the GIL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution is to create a fast data structure with only the lookup values,
I mean a key/value, a dict can be very fast.
After that, you must walk on the inputs and create the lookup-ed version.

```
import pandas as pd

list1=[['ENS_ID1','ENS_ID2','ENS_ID3'], ['ENS_ID10','ENS_ID3','ENS_ID2'] ] 

mapping = pd.DataFrame({'ENS_ID':['ENS_ID1','ENS_ID2','ENS_ID3','ENS_ID10'], 'MGI_ID':['MGI_ID1','MGI_ID2','MGI_ID2','MGI_ID10']})
    
lookup = dict(mapping[['ENS_ID','MGI_ID']].values)

# This is superfast
mapped_list = []
for l in list1:
    mapped_list.append([lookup[v] for v in l])

print(mapped_list)
# [['MGI_ID1', 'MGI_ID2', 'MGI_ID2'], ['MGI_ID10', 'MGI_ID2', 'MGI_ID2']]
```

ps: please correct the question with working code.

Answer (score 0):

As a quick solution you can try using listcomp instead of append, which should be faster:

`mgi_lists = [[mapping['MGI_ID'][mapping[mapping['ENSEMBL_ID']==i].index].values[0] for i in l] for l in ens_lists]`

Some explanations of why listcomp is faster are [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30245397/1089912)

Comment: This will probably not be appreciably faster.

Comment: Thank you for this first solution, but unfortunately as AKX said the difference it's not noticeable

Comment: One other small optimisation you could do is extract `mapping['MGI_ID']` out of the loop as it does not seem to change with the loop, so you wouldn't need to pay the cost of dict lookup per iteration, but again the speedup would probably be quite small.