# mitigating a performance warning from pandas (DataFrame is highly fragmented)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Suppose we have a function `bar(df)` that returns a numpy array of length `len(df)` given a dataframe `df`.

Now consider the idiom

```
def foo(df):
    for i in range(N):
        df['FOO_' + str(i)] = bar(df)
    return df
```

A recent pandas update started to cause the following warning

> PerformanceWarning: DataFrame is highly fragmented.  This is usually
> the result of calling `frame.insert` many times, which has poor
> performance.  Consider joining all columns at once using
> pd.concat(axis=1) instead.  To get a de-fragmented frame, use
> `newframe = frame.copy()`

As far as I understand, a way to mitigate this is to change the above code to the following idiom

```
def foo2(df):
    frames = [df]
    for i in range(N):
        frames += [pd.Series(bar(df), index=df.index)]
    return pd.concat(frames, axis=1)
```

The above code fixes the warning, but results in much worse execution times.

```
In [110]: %timeit foo()
1.73 s ± 11 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [111]: %timeit foo2()
2.51 s ± 25.1 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

A fix to suppress a performance warning that introduces extra overhead seems silly. Therefore my question is

> How can I fix the warning while also obtaning better performance. In other words, is there a way to improve the function foo2 to offer better performance than foo?

Comment: In your example, is `N` equal to the length of `df`? Also, I don't think `foo` would run as it's written in your example: `df[i]` looks for column `i`, not row `i`. Another problem is that `foo` overwrites the passed-in DataFrame `df`.

Comment: @PeterLeimbigler N is arbitrary, usually something large. I've edited the code to reflect your remark about df[i]. As for the overwrite, I am fine with that but curious : what's the polite way to do this?

Comment: @Jernej could you share some data and `bar()` body?

Comment: @DanilaGanchar There are multiple situations where this kind of idiom is used. I'd like to see a solution that is not tied to a particular implementation of data or the bar function.

Answer (score 6):

A very efficient and elegant way to build up a dataframe column-wise from numpy arrays is to build a dictionary of the columns and then convert them at once to the desired dataframe, since this means the cost for consolidating the data and managing the indexing has to be paid only once.

If I extend @SultanOrazbayev's [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70533089/2873952) with a `foo2_dict` variant:

```
def foo2_dict(df):
    new_columns = pd.DataFrame({f"FOO_{i}": bar(df) for i in range(N)}, index=df.index)
    return pd.concat([df, new_columns], axis=1)
```

I see an additional factor 6 improvement from `foo2_opt` (390ms) to `foo2_dict` (58ms), but this is of course highly dependent on the actual implementation of the underlying `bar` function.

Note also that the speed improvement by using the dictionary comprehension is of secondary order to the bunch numpy -> pandas conversion, ie. a `foo2_incremental_dict` takes 59ms for me.

```
def foo2_incremental_dict(df):
    new_columns = {}
    for i in range(N):
        new_columns[f"FOO_{i}"] = bar(df)
    new_columns = pd.DataFrame(new_columns, index=df.index)

    return pd.concat([df, new_columns], axis=1)
```

Answer (score 2):

One opportunity to optimize the code is to reframe `+=` as a list comprehension:

```py
import pandas as pd

N = 5000
df = pd.DataFrame(index=[_ for _ in range(100)])


def bar(df):
    return np.random.rand(len(df))


def foo2_orig(df):
    frames = [df]
    for i in range(N):
        frames += [pd.Series(bar(df), index=df.index)]
    return pd.concat(frames, axis=1)


def foo2_opt(df):
    frames = pd.concat([pd.Series(bar(df), index=df.index) for i in range(N)], axis=1)
    return pd.concat([df, frames], axis=1)
```

On my machine I see a factor of 2 performance improvement, although I'm not sure if the 100 rows and 5000 columns are realistic for your situation. The reason for speed-up is that [list comprehensions are more efficient](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30245465/10693596).

Update:

if the list of column names is known (`list_col_names`), then the individual series can be assigned custom column names using `name` kwarg:

```py
def foo2_opt(df):
    frames = pd.concat([pd.Series(bar(df), index=df.index, name=col_name) for i, col_name in zip(range(N), list_col_names)], axis=1)
    return pd.concat([df, frames], axis=1)
```

Comment: I can confirm that this seem to be working really well. Two follow up questions - why exactly is the second version more efficient? And, is it possible to set up custom names for the newly created columns? We can assume a list of strings of length N is given.

Comment: I updated the answer with a link to a better explanation for efficiency boost and the custom naming of columns.