# find triangular sum of an array (leetcode question)

Tags: python

https://leetcode.com/problems/find-triangular-sum-of-an-array/

So I am solving this leetcode problem and have come up with the following solution

```
class Solution:
    def triangularSum(self, nums: List[int]) -> int:
        arrLen = len(nums)
        newArr = []

        while len(nums) != 2:
            for i in range(0, arrLen - 1):
                total = (nums[i] + nums[i + 1])
                total %= 10
                newArr.append(total)

            nums = newArr
            arrLen = len(nums)
            newArr = []
        
        res = nums[0] + nums[1]
        return res
```

So It passes the test case, but when I press submit I get a Time Limit Exceeded error.
The details say, 1 / 300 test cases passed. STATUS: Time Limit Exceeded.

Did I do something wrong with my algorithm? Or is there some way to make it faster? I am really lost

Comment: Problems like this often require you to figure out a mathematical trick so you don't just do all the loops, because for large input the number of loops will be too much.

Comment: There is something wrong, but also yes, too slow.  Consider nums =[8,8]

Comment: You need to use `% 10` in the final addition.

Comment: Thanks I edited the final addition to do % 10. So I've learned about memoization before but only used it with recursion and dynamic programming. Would you recommend memoization for this? For example creating a dictionary and checking it before doing other operations?

Comment: Here's a hint: The total of a row will be `nums[0] + nums[-1] + 2 * sum(nums[1:-1])`. In each iteration there will be 1 less numbers in the row. Figure out how these sums propagate through the entire computation, and figure out a closed-form formula for it. You also don't need to do `% 10` at every iteration, you can calculate the final total and then the modulus of that.

Comment: @Barmar in the implementation I've done just doing ```%10``` at the end instead of at each iteration actually made it slower

Comment: @DanielHao I don't think this is related to Pascal's triangle, which is related to probability and binomial distributions.

Comment: @Barmar it is, see my edit

Comment: @Barmar If that's not what you meant with your hint, then what is?

Comment: @Nin17 I could be wrong, I'm not a math expert.

Answer (score 1):

A quick search for "time limit exceeded" and leetcode gives the following result: [enter link description here](https://support.leetcode.com/hc/en-us/articles/360011883714-What-is-the-difference-between-Time-Limit-Exceeded-TLE-and-Timeout-)

With this information.

> If your solution is judged Time Limit Exceeded, it could be one of the following reasons:
>
> Your code has an underlying infinite loop.
> Your algorithm is too slow and has a high time complexity.
> The data structure you returned is in an invalid state. For example, a linked list that contains a cycle.

Think about those three things.

Answer (score 0):

You can make it faster by using a list comprehension instead:

```
class Solution:
    def triangularSum(self, nums: List[int]) -> int:
        while len(nums) != 1:
            nums = [(nums[i]+nums[i+1])%10 for i in range(len(nums)-1)]
        return nums[0]
```

which gives an output of:
[image]

Edit: Here's another method that is definitely faster:

```
class Solution:    
    def triangularSum(self, nums: List[int]) -> int:
        # The idea of this is similar to the Pascal's triangle. 
        # If you deconstruct graph from the first example of [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] which is 48 -> 8
        # The coefficient for each number is [1, 4, 6, 4, 1] which is equivalent of row (n-1) in Pascal's triangle

        coefs = self.getRow(len(nums) - 1)

        return sum(num*coef for num, coef in zip(nums, coefs))%10

    @staticmethod
    def getRow(rowIndex: int):
        result = 1 
        yield result
        for i in range(rowIndex, 0, -1):
            result = result * i // (rowIndex+1-i)
            yield result
```

which gives an output of
[image]

Comment: mod 10 at the end helps reduce the time quite a bit

Comment: I found it made it slower? maybe idk the timings on their website seem a bit erratic. Im also finding it slower having ```%10``` at the end using timeit

Comment: Thanks for this solution, can I ask you why the list comprehension is faster? Isn't it doing the same operations?

Comment: explained better here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30245397/why-is-a-list-comprehension-so-much-faster-than-appending-to-a-list but essentially it doesn't need to call ```append```

Comment: While list comprehension is indeed a bit faster, it's not *infinitely* faster.

Comment: @KellyBundy still faster and satisfies the question 'is there a way to make it faster?'???

Comment: Maybe. I'm actually not sure. Is "faster" really an appropriate description? I mean, they have an *infinite* loop and you *fixed* it.

Comment: @KellyBundy it is faster, OPs doesn't have an infinite loop for all inputs

Comment: Not for *all* inputs, but for the second one they do.

Comment: @KellyBundy well for an input that doesn't result in an infinite loop in theirs, mine is faster -> faster

Comment: @KellyBundy I've added another method that is undisputedly faster / better algorithm

Comment: @Hodala22 I've added a better answer

Comment: @Nin17 Thats a really cool algorithm ,I learned a lot and really appreciate it!