# Why is this loop faster than a dictionary comprehension for creating a dictionary?

Tags: python, python-3.x, performance, python-internals, dictionary-comprehension

I don't come from a software/computer science background but I love to code in Python and can generally understand why things are faster. I am really curious to know why this for loop runs faster than the dictionary comprehension. Any insights?

> Problem : Given a dictionary `a` with these keys and values, return a dictionary with the values as keys and the keys as values. (challenge: do this in one line)

and the code

```
a = {'a':'hi','b':'hey','c':'yo'}

b = {}
for i,j in a.items():
    b[j]=i

%% timeit 932 ns ± 37.2 ns per loop

b = {v: k for k, v in a.items()}

%% timeit 1.08 µs ± 16.4 ns per loop
```

Comment: That's a mighty small dictionary to test that with..

Comment: Does similar timing hold true for a larger dictionary?  Having only 3 elements is not much of a test.   [Edit: beaten to the punch by Martijn!  I'm glad I'm not the only one who thought 3 was a small number :-) ]

Comment: When I do this with a dictionary with 1000 random keys and values, the dictcomp is marginally slightly faster. But not by much.

Comment: Thank you so much for all your responses, my apologies I should have tested with a larger dictionary.

Answer (score 84):

You are testing with way too small an input; while a dictionary comprehension doesn't have as much of a performance advantage against a `for` loop when compared to a list comprehension, for realistic problem sizes it can and does beat `for` loops, especially when targeting a global name.

Your input consists of just 3 key-value pairs. Testing with 1000 elements instead, we see that the timings are very close instead:

```
>>> import timeit
>>> from random import choice, randint; from string import ascii_lowercase as letters
>>> looped = '''\
... b = {}
... for i,j in a.items():
...     b[j]=i
... '''
>>> dictcomp = '''b = {v: k for k, v in a.items()}'''
>>> def rs(): return ''.join([choice(letters) for _ in range(randint(3, 15))])
...
>>> a = {rs(): rs() for _ in range(1000)}
>>> len(a)
1000
>>> count, total = timeit.Timer(looped, 'from __main__ import a').autorange()
>>> (total / count) * 1000000   # microseconds per run
66.62004760000855
>>> count, total = timeit.Timer(dictcomp, 'from __main__ import a').autorange()
>>> (total / count) * 1000000   # microseconds per run
64.5464928005822
```

The difference is there, the dict comp is faster but only *just* at this scale. With 100 times as many key-value pairs the difference is a bit bigger:

```
>>> a = {rs(): rs() for _ in range(100000)}
>>> len(a)
98476
>>> count, total = timeit.Timer(looped, 'from __main__ import a').autorange()
>>> total / count * 1000  # milliseconds, different scale!
15.48140200029593
>>> count, total = timeit.Timer(dictcomp, 'from __main__ import a').autorange()
>>> total / count * 1000  # milliseconds, different scale!
13.674790799996117
```

which is not *that* big a difference when you consider both processed nearly 100k key-value pairs. Still, the `for` loop is clearly *slower*.

So why the speed difference with 3 elements? Because a comprehension (dictionary, set, list comprehensions or a generator expression) is under the hood implemented as a new *function*, and calling that function has a base cost the plain loop doesn't have to pay.

Here's the disassembly for the bytecode for both alternatives; note the `MAKE_FUNCTION` and `CALL_FUNCTION` opcodes in the top-level bytecode for the dict comprehension, there is a separate section for what that function then does, and there are actually very few differences in between the two approaches here:

```
>>> import dis
>>> dis.dis(looped)
  1           0 BUILD_MAP                0
              2 STORE_NAME               0 (b)

  2           4 SETUP_LOOP              28 (to 34)
              6 LOAD_NAME                1 (a)
              8 LOAD_METHOD              2 (items)
             10 CALL_METHOD              0
             12 GET_ITER
        >>   14 FOR_ITER                16 (to 32)
             16 UNPACK_SEQUENCE          2
             18 STORE_NAME               3 (i)
             20 STORE_NAME               4 (j)

  3          22 LOAD_NAME                3 (i)
             24 LOAD_NAME                0 (b)
             26 LOAD_NAME                4 (j)
             28 STORE_SUBSCR
             30 JUMP_ABSOLUTE           14
        >>   32 POP_BLOCK
        >>   34 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             36 RETURN_VALUE
>>> dis.dis(dictcomp)
  1           0 LOAD_CONST               0 (<code object <dictcomp> at 0x11d6ade40, file "<dis>", line 1>)
              2 LOAD_CONST               1 ('<dictcomp>')
              4 MAKE_FUNCTION            0
              6 LOAD_NAME                0 (a)
              8 LOAD_METHOD              1 (items)
             10 CALL_METHOD              0
             12 GET_ITER
             14 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             16 STORE_NAME               2 (b)
             18 LOAD_CONST               2 (None)
             20 RETURN_VALUE

Disassembly of <code object <dictcomp> at 0x11d6ade40, file "<dis>", line 1>:
  1           0 BUILD_MAP                0
              2 LOAD_FAST                0 (.0)
        >>    4 FOR_ITER                14 (to 20)
              6 UNPACK_SEQUENCE          2
              8 STORE_FAST               1 (k)
             10 STORE_FAST               2 (v)
             12 LOAD_FAST                1 (k)
             14 LOAD_FAST                2 (v)
             16 MAP_ADD                  2
             18 JUMP_ABSOLUTE            4
        >>   20 RETURN_VALUE
```

The material differences: the looped code uses `LOAD_NAME` for `b` each iteration, and `STORE_SUBSCR` to store the key-value pair in dict loaded. The dictionary comprehension uses `MAP_ADD` to achieve the same thing as `STORE_SUBSCR` but doesn't have to load that `b` name each time.

But with *3 iterations only*, the `MAKE_FUNCTION` / `CALL_FUNCTION` combo the dict comprehension has to execute is the real drag on the performance:

```
>>> make_and_call = '(lambda i: None)(None)'
>>> dis.dis(make_and_call)
  1           0 LOAD_CONST               0 (<code object <lambda> at 0x11d6ab270, file "<dis>", line 1>)
              2 LOAD_CONST               1 ('<lambda>')
              4 MAKE_FUNCTION            0
              6 LOAD_CONST               2 (None)
              8 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             10 RETURN_VALUE

Disassembly of <code object <lambda> at 0x11d6ab270, file "<dis>", line 1>:
  1           0 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
              2 RETURN_VALUE
>>> count, total = timeit.Timer(make_and_call).autorange()
>>> total / count * 1000000
0.12945385499915574
```

More than 0.1 μs to create a function object with one argument, and call it (with an extra `LOAD_CONST` for the `None` value we pass in)! And that's just about the difference between the looped and comprehension timings for 3 key-value pairs.

You can liken this to being surprised that a man with a shovel can dig a small hole faster than a backhoe can. The backhoe can certainly dig fast, but a man with a shovel can get started faster if you need to get the backhoe started and moved into position first!

Beyond a few key-value pairs (digging a bigger hole), the function create and call cost fades away into nothingness. At this point the dict comprehension and the explicit loop *basically* do the same thing:

- take the next key-value pair, pop those on the stack
- call the `dict.__setitem__` hook via a bytecode operation with the top two items on the stack (either `STORE_SUBSCR` or `MAP_ADD`. This doesn't count as a 'function call' as it's all internally handled in the interpreter loop.

This is different from a list comprehension, where the plain loop version would have to use `list.append()`, involving an attribute lookup, and a function call *each loop iteration*. The list comprehension speed advantage comes from this difference; see [Python list comprehension expensive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14124610/python-list-comprehension-expensive)

What a dict comprehension does add, is that the target dictionary name only needs to be looked up once, when binding `b` to the the final dictionary object. If the target dictionary is a *global* instead of a local variable, the comprehension wins, hands down:

```
>>> a = {rs(): rs() for _ in range(1000)}
>>> len(a)
1000
>>> namespace = {}
>>> count, total = timeit.Timer(looped, 'from __main__ import a; global b', globals=namespace).autorange()
>>> (total / count) * 1000000
76.72348440100905
>>> count, total = timeit.Timer(dictcomp, 'from __main__ import a; global b', globals=namespace).autorange()
>>> (total / count) * 1000000
64.72114819916897
>>> len(namespace['b'])
1000
```

So just use a dict comprehension. The difference with < 30 elements to process is too small to care about, and the moment you are generating a global or have more items, the dict comprehension wins out anyway.

Comment: So from what you are saying, Martijn, can it be concluded that comprehensions are really just for improving readability of code? And from the last segment in your answer, it also seems as though all dictionary comprehensions can be written with for loops but not vice-versa?

Comment: @Rook: **dictionary** comprehensions only have a small speed advantage inside a function. Other comprehensions have a better chance to be faster, **provided you use them for their purpose**, so building a list or a dict or a set. All comprehensions can be written with a regular loop, but that's not being discussed here.

Answer (score 18):

This question, in some senses, is quite similar to [Why is a list comprehension so much faster than appending to a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30245397/why-is-a-list-comprehension-so-much-faster-than-appending-to-a-list/30245465#30245465) which I've answered a long while ago. However, the reason that this behavior is surprising to you is obviously because your dictionary is way too small to overcome the cost of creating a new function frame and pushing/pulling it in stack. To understand that better let's go under the skin of tow snippets you have:

```
In [1]: a = {'a':'hi','b':'hey','c':'yo'}
   ...: 
   ...: def reg_loop(a):
   ...:     b = {}
   ...:     for i,j in a.items():
   ...:         b[j]=i
   ...:         

In [2]: def dict_comp(a):
   ...:     b = {v: k for k, v in a.items()}
   ...:     

In [3]: 

In [3]: %timeit reg_loop(a)
529 ns ± 7.89 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)

In [4]: 

In [4]: %timeit dict_comp(a)
656 ns ± 5.39 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)

In [5]: 

In [5]: import dis

In [6]: dis.dis(reg_loop)
  4           0 BUILD_MAP                0
              2 STORE_FAST               1 (b)

  5           4 SETUP_LOOP              28 (to 34)
              6 LOAD_FAST                0 (a)
              8 LOAD_METHOD              0 (items)
             10 CALL_METHOD              0
             12 GET_ITER
        >>   14 FOR_ITER                16 (to 32)
             16 UNPACK_SEQUENCE          2
             18 STORE_FAST               2 (i)
             20 STORE_FAST               3 (j)

  6          22 LOAD_FAST                2 (i)
             24 LOAD_FAST                1 (b)
             26 LOAD_FAST                3 (j)
             28 STORE_SUBSCR
             30 JUMP_ABSOLUTE           14
        >>   32 POP_BLOCK
        >>   34 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             36 RETURN_VALUE

In [7]: 

In [7]: dis.dis(dict_comp)
  2           0 LOAD_CONST               1 (<code object <dictcomp> at 0x7fbada1adf60, file "<ipython-input-2-aac022159794>", line 2>)
              2 LOAD_CONST               2 ('dict_comp.<locals>.<dictcomp>')
              4 MAKE_FUNCTION            0
              6 LOAD_FAST                0 (a)
              8 LOAD_METHOD              0 (items)
             10 CALL_METHOD              0
             12 GET_ITER
             14 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             16 STORE_FAST               1 (b)
             18 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             20 RETURN_VALUE
```

On second disassembled code (dict comprehension) you have a `MAKE_FUNCTION` opcode which as it's also stated in documentation [pushes a new function object on the stack.](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/dis.html#opcode-MAKE_FUNCTION) and later `CALL_FUNCTION` which [Calls a callable object with positional arguments.](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/dis.html#opcode-CALL_FUNCTION) and then:

> pops all arguments and the callable object off the stack, calls the callable object with those arguments, and pushes the return value returned by the callable object.

All these operations have their costs but when the dictionary gets larger the cost of assigning the key-value items to the dictionary will become larger than creating a function under the hood. In other words cost of calling the `__setitem__` method of the dictionary from a certain point will exceed the cost of creating and suspending a dictionary object on the fly.

Also, note that certainly there are multiple other operations (OP_CODES in this case) that play a crucial role in this game which I think worth investigating and considering which I'm gonna live it to you as a practice ;).