# What is a more efficient way to extract sub-dicts from a list of dicts in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm

I have a json like this:

```
{
    "team": [
        {
            "id": "1",
            "member_name": "name1",
            "some_other_key":"keyvalue1"                
        },
        {
            "id": "2",
            "member_name": "name2",
            "some_other_key": "keuvalue2"

        }
    ]
}
```

And I want to create a dict like this

```
 { "1": "name1","2":"name2"}
```

I have written code like this

```
user_mapping = {}
for user in users['team']:
    user_mapping[user['id']] = user['member_name']
```

but I wanted to know if there's a more pythonic way or efficient way to do this than the brute force approach I've used.

Comment: dict comprehension

Comment: How could you do this *other* than "brute force"? You have to iterate over all of the items.

Comment: @jonrsharpe see the answers

Comment: @GPhilo neither of those use a different *algorithm*, though, do they? They're still brute force insofar as they can't take shortcuts to get to the result; it's a fundamentally O(n) operation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, at least one: Comprehensions

```
user_mapping = { user['id']:user['member_name'] for user in users['team'] }
```

comprehensions are both faster and more pythonic than for loops

Answer (score 4):

Simply and straightforward:

```
user_mapping = {user['id']: user['member_name'] for user in users['team']}
```

Besides, your `for loop` approach is not a "brute-force". You would use the former approach when you need a more extended logic (with intermediate statements/conditions/expressions).

Comment: Is dict comprehension faster in this case?

Comment: @SujayDSa https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52542742/why-is-this-loop-faster-than-a-dictionary-comprehension-for-creating-a-dictionar