# Can this conditional be shortened?

Tags: python

Is it possible to just use `.get()` function from dictionary for this? Is this the best we can do to shorten this piece of code?

`n_dict` is a `Dict` type (uppercase `D`) and `NES` is just a list of `str`

```
eted_info = {}
for key in n_dict:
    if key in NES:
        eted_info[key] = n_dict[key]
```

I'm just curious if there is a better / more pythonic way to retrieve a value, like C# has with `TryGetValue`.

Comment: What are `n_dict` and `NES`?

Comment: edited to show types

Comment: Most pythonic way would probably be to use a dict comprehension.

Comment: `eted_info` **only** contains keys that are in `NES`?  ... No keys with null values? How many items in `NES`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think a dictionary comprehension and using `n_dict.items()` is the cleanest way of doing this

```
n_dict = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}

NES = ['a', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j']

eted_info = {key:value for key,value in n_dict.items() if key in NES}

print(eted_info)
```

RESULT

```
{'a': 1, 'c': 3}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do something with dictionary comprehension like this:

```
eted_info = {key: n_dict[key] for key in n_dict if key in NES}
```

Comment: thanks man, that definitely looks better :) is there any performance difference?

Comment: It is slightly faster, but not by much in most cases: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52542742/why-is-this-loop-faster-than-a-dictionary-comprehension-for-creating-a-dictionar

Comment: Slight variation using `items()`:  `eted_info = {k: v for k, v in n_dict.items() if k in NES}`

Comment: Another using sets (might be more performant if `NES` and `ndict` are very large, since it avoids O(n^2) lookups): `eted_info = {k: n_dict[k] for k in set(n_dict) & set(NES)}`

Comment: @Samwise Would you mind posting that second one as an answer? I don't find it as readable for likely use, but as you said, for very large `NES` and `ndict`, it's quite slick.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to avoid the O(n^2) operation of iterating through each item in `NES` for each item in `n_dict`, you can build a list of keys as a `set` intersection and iterate through that:

```
eted_info = {k: n_dict[k] for k in set(n_dict) & set(NES)}
```

Answer (score 1):

Iterate over **keys** in `NES`; use `n_dict.get.get` with a default of `None`; conditionally add to `eted_info`.

```
for key in NES:
    v = n_dict.get(key,None)
    if v: eted_info[key] = v
```

- This will only iterate over the list once regardless of the length of n_dict.
- Assumes all values in `n_dict` are truthy. Other *placeholders* could be used for the default value.

Comment: You could write that as a dict-comprehension::

eted_info = {key:n_dict[key] for key in NES if key in n_dict}

Pretty much the same as @AndrewWei but the small difference saves a bit of complexity.

Comment: @AnneAunyme - yes you could! Feel free to add (edit) that to my answer.