# Generating tuples from dictionary key and it's values

Tags: python, dictionary

I have list of dictionaries each key mapped to list

```
[    {28723408: [28723409]},
     {28723409: [28723410]},
     {28723410: [28723411, 28723422]},
     {28723411: [28723412]},
     {28723412: [28723413]},
     {28723413: [28723414, 28, 28723419]}]
```

I want to create list of tuples key mapped to each list value:

```
[(28723408, 28723409),
 (28723409, 28723410),
 (28723410, 28723411),
 (28723410, 28723422),
 (28723411, 28723412),
 (28723412, 28723413),
 (28723413, 28723414),
 (28723413, 28),
 (28723413, 28723419),]
```

I did it following way:

```
for pairs in self.my_pairs:
    for source, targets in pairs.items():
        for target in targets:
            pair_list.append((source, target))
```

Is there more Pythonic way doing so ?

Comment: All the fancy oneliners I tried ended up way less readable than what you did.

Comment: Are the keys in your list of dictionaries known to be distinct and what is supposed to happen otherwise?

Comment: @guidot, they not distinct. I just need to make mapping no filters needed.

Comment: Does each dict have exactly a single key?

Comment: @RiccardoBucco , please don't make this assumption.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do exactly what you have already done, but using a list comprehension.

```
pair_list = [(source, target)
             for pairs in self.my_pairs
             for source, targets in pairs.items()
             for target in targets]
```

This approach might look identical to yours, but it is much faster! Check for example [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30245397/why-is-a-list-comprehension-so-much-faster-than-appending-to-a-list) question (or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14124610/python-list-comprehension-expensive)). This fact is confirmed also [here](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonSpeed/PerformanceTips#Loops).

If you want a more "pythonic" approach you could also use `itertools.product` and `itertools.chain`:

```
from itertools import chain, product

pair_list = list(chain(*(product((source,), targets)
                         for pairs in self.my_pairs
                         for source, targets in pairs.items())))
```

Comment: I was about to post a similar answer using list comprehension. Very nice!